# background worker application

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

When user open Google Maps application, my application will be active. For example user go from one place to another when Google Maps say "Turn Left", my application will listen google maps and will send the data via bluetooth to another device. I'am new in this project so I don't know where to start. I have two question.
1- How can I run my application in the background? What should I investigate to do this?
2- How can I listen Google Maps application?

Answer (score 0):

1) To run a background worker you need to create a service :

First create a class that extends `android.app.Service`, for example - `BackgroundService`.
Then call it from your current activity (`MyActivity`):

```
startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, BackgroundService.class));
```

Notice that you are not constantly creating the process...

For more, read: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

2) To get info from google maps -you can use one of the provided listeners to the googlemaps from the [Google Play services Location API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), such as the [LocationListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener).

Comment: Note that these days ( android >= 8, which is most new phones), you need to start the service with startForegroundService, and put a notification up. Not using this will result in the service stopping within a few minutes.